# Office Javascript upload to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to upload a Word document to AWS S3 from an Office Javascript add-in.

Following along with the sample (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/develop/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-powerpoint-or-word.md), I can get the content, but when it is sent to S3 (using a pre-signed URL), the resulting file never seems to be a valid docx file. Opening the file in a text editor shows that the content is simply the text representation of the raw data that was sent.

Comment: 1. How are you encoding the file to base 64 and how are you decoding it? 2. If you change the extension from .docx to .zip, can you unzip the file? If so, does it have the OPC folders and files that would be expected?

Answer (score -1):

The issue was in AWS S3 not interpreting the content as a file/binary data and therefore saving it as plain text.

The below code, where `data` is a binary array, behaves as expected:

```
fetch(signedUrl, {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': WORD_MIME_TYPE
  },
  body: new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)], {type: WORD_MIME_TYPE})
})
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob for information on `Blob`.